# What does "You shake my nerves" and "Shake off the nerves" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Yesterday,I was having conversation with my friend and i told him something about someone which was really surprising and he replied to me "You really shake my nerves" and i didn't get him but later i was trying to search online the meaning but i didn't find any pleasing answer instead i get more confused because i found some new phrase like "shake off the nerves" which i also don't know what it means? I also found some questions on internet where people have asked like "How to shake nerves before interview?" so i also want to know difference if there is any between "shake off the nerves" and "shake nerves".

Comment: It's not a natural saying in English that I've ever heard (in American English). Sure, when you are nervous, it is natural to say "I need to calm my nerves". It's also natural to say "I need to shake off this feeling", but really you just don't put those two together.

Comment: Jerry Lee Lewis had an issue with someone *shaking his nerves*. (Also, *rattling his brain*)

Answer (score 1):

Saad, in my home dialect (Appalachian), if I found myself in an agitated emotional state, I would say that I need to "shake off my nerves" (that is, I need to calm my overwrought emotional state).  We have several related "shake" idioms specific to various emotions:  shake off this feeling, shake off my anger, shake off this depression, and so on.  We don't have an idiom comparable to "You shake my nerves", but I understand your friend's meaning in context:  He seems to have said that your surprising story put him in a bit of an emotional tizzy (that is, the story shook his nerves).